# Social Field Module: Icons not showing up in options

Tags: 7

Trying to use [Social Field Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/socialfield) for general user Profile. Followed through module text but no icons appear to show up for the module in either the Field itself or from an End-user logged in perspective. Installed Font Icon Module also.

Anyone any ideas why this is? Module seems quite simple, but maybe I'm missing something or it's lost in translation somewhere.

[image]

Comment: does it have permissions, and are they set correctly?

Comment: It does I they appear correct. The guy says on his page:SUB-MODULES

In addition to the core Social field module, you are able to enable the following sub-module:

Font icons (font_icons): Loads fontello icons. You must download fontello library to sites/all/libraries/fontello folder. You can download fontello from http://fontello.com.

Comment: do you get any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

Just copy "font" and "Css" folder in your activated theme and if it ask to merge just allow them to merge and check further.

Hope this helps you.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am working with an omega base theme and here is how I fixed it:

1. Copy the font folder with its files into your own theme folder, so it is located at sites/all/themes/YOURTHEME/font/
2. Create a _fontello.scss file in one of your sass directories, I put mine in base. So your path is sites/all/themes/YOURTHEME/sass/base/_fontello.scss
3. Copy the css code from the fontello.css located in the css folder and paste it in the _fontello.scss file
4. Don't forget to save and clear your cache

note: You will also have to do this in your admin theme because they use separate templates and stylesheets.
To make it easy, just paste the css code in a style.css file.

Hope this helps